# how to add a rect around a word in corona sdk?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

What is the right way to know the frame of a word inside of a line in Corona SDK? in other words, I want to add a rect above a specific word, I tried using webview instead and `mark` tag but the webview keeps flickering on iOS, so the webview solution is canceled.

[image: highlight]

I have added a rect manually into this word, but what is the best way that I specify a word and know it's frame so I highlight it with the rect, like move the rect to the next word? the font I use is Arial, and it's not monospaced.

```
          local myRect = display.newRect(20,165,32,12.5)
          myRect.alpha = 0.5
          myRect:setFillColor(1,1,0)
          myRect.anchorX = 0

          local myString = "Word is highlighted"
          local line = display.newText(myString,  0,165, "Arial", 12.5)
          line.anchorX = 0
          line.x = 20
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: couldnt change the text colour to distinguish?

Comment: if you know a way to change a word color, please add an answer.

Comment: The whole text is just an object and you only have control over the whole text. The only way I know is to separate each word to an object and colour it anyway you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would just write additional function for that. Something like:

```
function highlightedText(pre, high, post, x, y, font, size)
    local text = display.newText("", x, y, font, size)
    local dx, rectangle = 0
    if pre then
        local t = display.newText(pre, 0, 0, font, size)
        text.text = pre
        dx = t.width
        -- We need to add line below according to Corona Docs
        text.anchorX = 0 text.x = x text.y = y
        t:removeSelf()
    end
    if high then
        local t = display.newText(high, 0, 0, font, size)
        rectangle = display.newRect(x+dx, y, t.width, t.height)
        rectangle:toBack()
        text.text = text.text .. high
        -- We need to add line below according to Corona Docs
        text.anchorX = 0 text.x = x text.y = y
        t:removeSelf()
    end
    if post then
        text.text = text.text .. post
        -- We need to add line below according to Corona Docs
        text.anchorX = 0 text.x = x text.y = y
    end
    return text, rectangle, dx -- `dx` passed in case of moving whole text along with rectangle
end

local text, rect, _ = highlightedText("The", "word", "is highlighted.", 10, 10, "Arial", 12.5)

rect.alpha = 0.5
rect:setFillColor(1,1,0)
rect.strokeWidth = 3

text:setFillColor(1,1,1)
```

I'm no expert in Corona but this should work just fine with **single-line static** text.

Comment: this is not very precise, but it is similar to the solution I found, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
local player2 = display.newText("test221234567890", 210, 210 )
player2:setFillColor( 0.6, 0.4, 0.8 )

local myRectangle = display.newRect( player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height )
myRectangle.strokeWidth = 3
myRectangle:setFillColor( 0.5 )
myRectangle:toBack()
```

Comment: i want to highlight a word from a whole text, not the whole text.